# Firebase web realtime database not updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update my firebase realtime database with user info when I am creating new user through firebase password authentication. And on successful sign in I am moving to another page. The problem is that my database is not getting updated in the above scenario however if stay in the login page and don't change to any other url; the database gets updated.

Here's my create user code

```
firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        var user = userCredential.user;
        if (user !== null) {
            const db = firebase.database();
            db.ref("/").set({
                uid: user.uid,
            });
        }
        // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
        // ..
    });
```

And here's where I'm switching to another page,

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
        var uid = user.uid;
        console.log(user);
        //If I remove the below line, database is updated
        window.location.href = "../html/home.html";
        // ...
    } else {
        // User is signed out
        // ...
        console.log("not logged in");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls is asynchronous:

```
db.ref("/").set({
  uid: user.uid,
});
```

That means that the code continues to run after the `set()` function returns, and asynchronously sends the data to the database. But when you change `window.location`, it interrupts this write operation. That's also why it works when you don't send the user to a new location: the write operation can then complete without interruption.

A quick simple fix is to flag when you're updating the database:

```
isCreatingUser = true; //  Flag that we're creating a user
firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
        var user = userCredential.user;
        if (user !== null) {
            const db = firebase.database();
            db.ref("/").set({
                uid: user.uid,
            }).then(() => {
                isCreatingUser = false; //  We're done
                window.location.href = "../html/home.html";  //  Navigate away
            }).catch((e) => {
                isCreatingUser = false; //  We're done
                throw e;
            })
        }
        // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
        // ..
        isCreatingUser = false; //  We're done
    });
```

And then:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user && !isCreatingUser) {
        ...
```

You'll probably need some more synchronization, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: I tried using this status flag method and I can successfully update the database but now  the window.location is not executed. Do I need to do that asynchronously.

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to call that after the database write is completed since the `onAuthStateChanged` will have already run at that point. I updated my answer to show that.